# Saving bitmap to SdCard Android

Tags: android, bitmap, png, compression

I am writng a code to convert a png file back to bmp and save it on the sdcard. This is my current code.

```
    FileInputStream in;
    BufferedInputStream buf;
    try {
        in = new  FileInputStream("File_Path_to_Read.png");
        buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        byte[] bMapArray= new byte[buf.available()];
        buf.read(bMapArray);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);

        //Code segment to save on file
        int numBytesByRow = bMap.getRowBytes() * bMap.getHeight();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(numBytesByRow);
        bMap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
        byte[] bytes = byteBuffer.array();

        FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream("File_Path_To_Save.bmp");
        fileOuputStream.write(bytes);
        fileOuputStream.close();


        if (in != null) {
        in.close();
        }
        if (buf != null) {
        buf.close();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

I am having problem in saving the bMap to the Sdcard. All the examples I found use bMap.compress(). Using this method I can't save as bmp. Can someone give an example on how to save the bitmap on the Sdcard?

Edit:
I can now save the file as .bmp to sdcard. However it won't get to the original size. Any sugguestions on converting the PNG to BMP?

Comment: `bitmap .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out)`, whenever you use this method, the saved image's quality always changes so you have to try it yourself for the best fit by changing the 2 parameter of the method.

Comment: I know the image quality changes when you use the compress method. However the I am looking for a way to convert the JPEG back to BMP. The original BMP is like 80 Mb using my edited code, I get 14 KB. Obbviously the decompression is not working...Can converting back to BMP (from JPEG) be done on Android?

Answer (score 0):

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "My_Folder" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    File myFile = new File(root, "ABC.jpg");
    Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(myFile, 800, 600);
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getAbsoluteFile() + "/DEF.jpg");
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        bitmap.recycle();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f, int WIDTH, int HIGHT) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
        final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 2;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                scale *= 2;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
return null;
}
```

Comment: Just to add information to your reply: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() doesn't give you access to the external SD card.

Comment: @greywolf82 I'm assuming that 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` will be provided in the manifest:)

Comment: @AndroidWarrior This is saving as a .JPEG format. I want to convert the ABC.JPEG to DEF.bmp. Is this possible? with this code - bitmap .compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

Comment: `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out)`
It ony supports
Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG

Comment: `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out)`
It ony supports
**Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG**,
**Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG**,
**Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP**

Comment: yes. Any solution to convert JPEG, PNG, WEBP backto bmp?